# How to get iOS 9 version simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.4

1. I am using latest Xcode Version= 6.4
2. I tried to list of simulator availability, I am having 7.1,8.1,8.2, 8.3 and 8.4 iOS version.
3. I tried to see, if there is any new version of iOS simulator is available such as iOS 9 version in download simulator. I don't find iOS 9 version simulators option under download simulator list.
4. If I want to get iOS 9 version, what can I do? Does Xcode 6.4 supports for iOS 9 version?

Comment: You'll require Xcode 7 for that. You can RUN App on iOS 9 device using Xcode 6, But firstly you need to build your app on XCode 7, after that it will support on XCode 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Xcode 7 and you also need to ensure that your Mac OS is updated. I updated Xcode to 7.1 but the maximum iOS simulator version available was 8.4. I then updated my OS from Yosemite 10.10 to El Capitan, and now (with no additional updates to Xcode) the maximum iOS simulator version available is 9.1.